# JQuery offset.top on first element in object returning error

Tags: jquery

I'm sure there is a simple explanation but oddly enough I am unable to find it anywhere, so I am here!

I am trying to get the offset().top of only the first element returned in the Jquery object. I am convinced the following code is correct but I keep getting this error:

> TypeError: $(...)[0].offset is not a function

```js
var x = $('.class')[0].offset().top;
```

What am I missing? Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Accessing a jQuery object using bracket notation returns an Element object, not a jQuery object, and that has no `offset()` method.

To fix this your could use `eq()` instead:

```
var x = $('.class').eq(0).offset().top;
```

Or, in this case, `first()` will work too:

```
var x = $('.class').first.offset().top;
```

Also `:first`:

```
var x = $('.class:first').offset().top;
```